# I have an element on My persistent bottom sheet, how do I open a new Persistent bottom sheet if I tap the element on previous bottom sheet?

Tags: dart, flutter

Created a persistent bottom sheet when I press I button. The persistent bottom sheet contains multiple elements, how do I open a new persistent bottom sheet if I tap on any element on the previous persistent sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the `BuildContext` and open a new bottom sheet on tap:

```
showBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open another bottom sheet.'),
          onPressed: () => showBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => Text('Another bottom sheet.'))));
```